# Algorithm help: Walking the boundaries of a map

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to develop an online map editing program for a game that I play.
The data for the map is a little large.  A medium size map's data is close to 1 mb if I send the data for every square.

What I thought I could do was find the boundaries on the map and create polygons based off of that.

Currently I:

1. Find the northwestern most boundary and start there.  For my sample map, it's (3,2)
2. Then, check North, East, South, then West and go to the first unvisited location that does not have 1 as its data.
3. If there are no unvisited locations, go to the location that is the furthest back in the history.

[image: Sample Map]
[Steps Taken](http://pastebin.com/7XdRfCtZ)

This works fine, for northern areas.  However, when I get to a southern area, it checks north and finds that it's an unvisited location and goes to that.   The coordinates of where it messes up is at 13,11.

Obviously, this doesn't give me the boundary that I want and it doesn't walk the entire map.  So, something needs to change.

I considered adding a boundary check in the same order of operations as before(NESW).  However, it is possible to mess that up as well.

[image: Map2 - Boundary check]

At (13,11) it would check to the north and see that it's an unvisited location. And this time, there is a boundary there, so it would think it's ok to go there.

What should I do to walk the entire outer boundary?

I did take a look at the convex hull algorithm that is mentioned here, but I don't think it would be what I need.   I might be incorrect, but this is what I would expect the result of a convex hull to look like.
[image: Convex Hull]
While that does reduce the size of the map by a little bit, there is still a lot of data I don't need.  And when I need to get the internal borders of items in the map, the size reduction is lost because they would be irregular as well.

So, how would I ensure that I'm actually walking the outer border?

Comment: Well, I think convex hull really is what you need. Why don't you think so?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding how convex hull would work.  Wouldn't the black lines in the third image be the boundary returned by convex hull?  If I draw those lines and fill it in, it wouldn't be an accurate representation of the map.

Comment: Seems like RLE (run-length encoding) would compress this just fine.

Comment: @misplacedme Sorry, I mistook the 3rd image for the result you **want**.

Comment: RBarry, that is actually exactly what I was thinking I would do if I couldn't map only the boundaries.    Thanks.

Comment: Billiska, thanks.  At least I know that my understanding of that algorithm is correct now.

Comment: Have you consider this algorithm ... I don't know its name but it's very intuitive. Imagine if you're in a **dark labyrinth**. what do you do to make sure you traverse the whole labyrigth? Simple, just feel the wall to your left; turn left whether possible; turn right when forced to.

Comment: That's a good suggestion Billiska.  I hadn't considered reducing the number of directions I could go, but that would definately do what I need.

Comment: misplacedme please confirm if you think the algorithm I described is the one you want in order to find the **boundaries** of this map. Because if your ultimate goal is compression, then RLE as RBarryYoung is probably more direct.

Comment: As an estimate, storing the edges in the way you describe is going to take at least 2 bits per polygon + 2 bits per edge pixel. Storing the RLE version is going to take 2 bits + 5 bits per line for the given maps.  So RLE is almost certainly going to cost you less space. Even more so as the maps get bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the expansion of the answer I suggested in the comment.

> Imagine if you're in a dark labyrinth. what do you do to make sure you
>   traverse the whole labyrinth? Simple, just feel the wall to your left;
>   turn left whether possible; turn right when forced to.

Ok, more precisely:

1. Find a starting point on the boundary of the map, which I think you already know how.
2. Make sure to represent the current **facing** of your agent. (up,down,left,right)
3. Prioritize the **relative** direction of movement like this: (left, forwards, right, backwards)
4. Move in the prioritized direction if possible.
5. While walking, note down the visited position as part of the answer. And also check if you have come back to a visited place or not in order to terminate the program.

EDIT: correct the priority. left before forwards, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got a problem right, but it looks like the outer border can be presented as an array of orthogonal normal vectors. Or rather sections. Imagine a grid in which map squares belong to cells. Lets start marking our sections from the top left starting with 0. In that notation the beginning of outer border for pic. 1 would be ((3, 2), (4, 2)), ((4,2), (5,2)) and so on.

Every section, which belongs two cells, one of each is map square "1" and other not is a border. You can traverse through the grid and simply collect them.

Then you would have to sort them into cycles. That's easy. If two sections have one common coordinate - they do belong to the single cycle. If two cycles have a common coordinate beneath their sections - they are the one cycle, you just concatinate ones data to another.

When you have a set of definitely different cycles, the longest one, the one which has the most sections, would be your outer border.

If of course the map is in one piece.